# Any chances to imitate times() Ruby method in C#?

Tags: c#, ruby, language-features, cycle

Every time I need to do something *N* times inside an algorithm using C# I write this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Studying Ruby I have learned about method *times()* which can be used with the same semantics like this

```
N.times do
    ...
end
```

Code fragment in C# looks more complex and we should declare useless variable *i*.

I tried to write extension method which returns *IEnumerable*, but I am not satisfied with the result because again I have to declare a cycle variable *i*.

```
public static class IntExtender
{
    public static IEnumerable Times(this int times)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            yield return true;
    }
}

...

foreach (var i in 5.Times())
{
    ...
}
```

Is it possible using some new C# 3.0 language features to make *N* times cycle more elegant?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A slightly briefer version of [cvk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177538/any-chances-to-imitate-times-ruby-method-in-c#177551):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Times(this int count, Action action)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
        {
             action();
        }
    }

    public static void Times(this int count, Action<int> action)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
        {
             action(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
5.Times(() => Console.WriteLine("Hi"));
5.Times(i => Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}", i));
```

Answer (score 14):

It is indeed possible with C# 3.0:

```
public interface ILoopIterator
{
    void Do(Action action);
    void Do(Action<int> action);
}

private class LoopIterator : ILoopIterator
{
    private readonly int _start, _end;

    public LoopIterator(int count)
    {
        _start = 0;
        _end = count - 1;
    }

    public LoopIterator(int start, int end)
    {
        _start = start;
        _end = end;
    }  

    public void Do(Action action)
    {
        for (int i = _start; i <= _end; i++)
        {
            action();
        }
    }

    public void Do(Action<int> action)
    {
        for (int i = _start; i <= _end; i++)
        {
            action(i);
        }
    }
}

public static ILoopIterator Times(this int count)
{
    return new LoopIterator(count);
}
```

Usage:

```
int sum = 0;
5.Times().Do( i => 
    sum += i
);
```

Shamelessly stolen from http://grabbagoft.blogspot.com/2007/10/ruby-style-loops-in-c-30.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 3.5 then you can use the extension method Each proposed in this article, and use it to avoid classic loop.

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
  {
      public static void Each<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Action<T> action)
      {
          foreach(T item in source)
          {
              action(item);
          }
      }
  }
```

> This particular extension method spot
>   welds an Each method on anything that
>   implements IEnumerable. You know
>   this because the first parameter to
>   this method defines what this will be
>   inside the method body. Action is a
>   pre-defined class that basically
>   stands in for a function (delegate)
>   returning no value. Inside the method,
>   is where the elements are extracted
>   from the list. What this method
>   enables is for me to cleanly apply a
>   function in one line of code.

(http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linq-to-life.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own extension that add Times to Integer (plus some other stuff). You can get the code here : https://github.com/Razorclaw/Ext.NET

The code is very similar to Jon Skeet answer:

```
public static class IntegerExtension
{
    public static void Times(this int n, Action<int> action)
    {
        if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            action(i);
        }
    }
}
```